# Any javascript event for loading external JS on-the-fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've been working on a bookmarklet project that loads external jQuery.js file like this:

```
jq_script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
jq_script.type = 'text/javascript';
jq_script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq_script);
```

But when I try use jQuery right after this, I receive:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
> on the chrome JS console.

Is there any "event" that is called when a single DOM instance is loaded?
(or any event that gets triggered when an external JS file is loaded like this?)

Answer (score 3):

`<script>` elements have an `onload` event.

Comment: They have an `onload` property and a `load` event.

Comment: I believe onload on script tag is not supported in IE8 and below. We need to fo for onreadystatechange. REF : http://blog.andrewcantino.com/blog/2008/11/23/replacement-for-script-onload-in-ie/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
function loadScript()
{
 jq_script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
 jq_script.type = 'text/javascript';
 jq_script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js';
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq_script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

Comment: I don't think I can use window.onload event from bookmarklet...but I might be wrong, though... anyway, thanks for the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

**Update : Using latest jquery code below.**

jQuery's [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript) handles it in the below way. You can place your functionality inside `if(!isAbort)`.

```
script = document.createElement( "script" );

script.async = "async";

if ( s.scriptCharset ) {
    script.charset = s.scriptCharset;
}

script.src = s.url;

// Attach handlers for all browsers
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function( _, isAbort ) {

    if ( isAbort || !script.readyState || /loaded|complete/.test( script.readyState ) ) {

        // Handle memory leak in IE
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;

        // Remove the script
        if ( head && script.parentNode ) {
            head.removeChild( script );
        }

        // Dereference the script
        script = undefined;

        // Callback if not abort
        if ( !isAbort ) {
            //**Do your stuff here**
        }
    }
};
// Use insertBefore instead of appendChild  to circumvent an IE6 bug.
// This arises when a base node is used (#2709 and #4378).
head.insertBefore( script, head.firstChild );
```

Comment: @JamesChen I updated the above to use code from jQuery 1.7. You need to use onreadystatechange to support IE.